# JPA @OneToOne with an Entity that is not exported from it's OSGi Bundle

Tags: jpa, osgi

I am trying to set up a simple foreign key relation ship using JPA in a rather complex OSGi environment.

The two entities I want to use are structured in bundles like so:

```
masterbundle
|->org.masterpackage.persistence
   |-> MasterEntityDto.java
slavebundle
|->org.slavepackage.persistence
   |-> SlaveEntity.java
```

`SlaveEntity` want to refer to the `MasterEntityDto`like so

```
@Entity(name = "SlaveEntity")
public class SlaveEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "slaveID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "masterEntity_id")
  private MasterEntity masterEntity;
  // snip..
}
```

Now, this fails because `masterbundle` is not exporting  the MasterEntityDto (or its package), I think. We are using the Service Aspect of OSGi, masterBundle is `provide-interface`-ing a *service that is using the Dto* instead of the Dto. 
The exception I see when the bundle starts says, among other things `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle slavebundle [121]: Unable to resolve 121.8: missing requirement [121.8] osgi.wiring.package;`

**Question**: How do I create a `@OneToOne` relation from `SlaveEntity` to `MasterEntityDto`? Is this not possible in when using the OSGi service platform and I only expose services and not whole bundles / packages?

**Edit1**
As per request: `MasterEntityDto` has nothing fancy.

```
@Entity(name = "MasterEntityDto")
public class MasterEntityDto {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", length = 128)
private String masterId;
// snip 
}
```

I would want JPA to make a `SlaveEntity` - table with columns `SlaveId` (which is this tables PK) and `masterEntity_id` which would act as foreign key, pointing to table `MasterEntityDto`'s `id` column.

Comment: Can you show the code of your `MasterEntityDto`? Which column in your database contains the foreign key?

Comment: I updated my posting with code of `MasterEntityDto`. I am not sure whether this is really relevant. Also tried to describe what the table should look like. I am talking of a unidirectional one to one relationship, since I can't modify `MasterEntityDto`. I simply want to enhance it. Also, needles to say, the actual code is different - more complex and to long for this posting. This is just the essence of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages containing domain classes (such as MasterEntityDto) **do need to be exported**, so that the JPA bundle can have visibility to instantiate them.

Because of this it is very important to keep such packages separated from other packages containing implementation/logic code, which should be private.

Comment: I see. 
However, with the OSGi Service Platform one only exposes interfaces to service components (using `<provide-interface>` in a `<scr:component>`-definition). That means, if I want to use JPA properly I can't rely on the service functionality alone and need OSGi component functionality to expose certain packages (using `export-package` in some `manifest.mf`). Right? Just making sure I understand OSGi+JPA correctly.

Comment: Yes. This sentence added to satisfy StackOverflow minimum comment size rule.

Comment: Follow up Question. I still can't get it to work. I keep getting: `[SlaveEntity] uses a non-entity [MasterEntity] as target entity in the relationship… `. However `MasterEntity` IS a working Entity as you see. Both entities are defined in their respective `persistence.xml`s. Is it possible that just exporting the `MasterEntity`s package won't do since it does not contain `MasterEntity`s persistence.xml? (That would be in the bundle, not in a package).